# How to deploy java web start application on weblogic 11g?

Tags: java, weblogic11g

I have a java web start application deployed on Weblogic 8.1. All the signed jars are located in the weblogic/applications/webstart/lib folder. When I try to do the same in weblogic 11 using the same folder structure it is unable to start the application and access the files in instance:port/webstart/lib/. Do I need to explicitly deploy the same from Weblogic console?